# Oracle Apex: ORA-24344 Success with compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently working on an oracle database in APEX.

First of all, I do not have access to any tools. I can only use what is provided in apex.oracle.com and I am writing the script in NotePad++ before uploading it over there. It's a school assignment, so I am not allowed to use any other tools, even if there is something that would make things easier.

I am creating a long script that creates a bunch of tables in a database, creates a bunch of records in every table, and creates all the constraints. This part works fine. Now i must create several functions and procedures in the same script, after the other stuff.

Every single time I try to create one, I get this: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Also, the other instructions in the script after this error are not executed. Everything that was before the error works fine.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lHIjfcE.png]

Here is one of the functions that create this error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_03Recherche (titre_art VARCHAR2, nom_aut VARCHAR2, type_art VARCHAR2)
RETURN CURSOR
IS
    CURSOR articles (p_titre_art VARCHAR2, p_nom_aut VARCHAR2, p_type_art VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT * FROM BI_Articles INNER JOIN (BI_ArticlesAuteurs INNER JOIN BI_Auteurs ON BI_ArticlesAuteurs.AuteurID = BI_Auteurs.AuteurID) ON BI_Articles.ISBN = BI_ArticlesAuteurs.ISBN
    WHERE (Titre LIKE p_titre_art) AND ((Nom LIKE p_nom_aut) OR (Prenom LIKE p_nom_aut)) AND TypeArticle LIKE type_art;
BEGIN
    RETURN articles(titre_art, nom_aut, type_art);
END;
```

Comment: What does `show error` give you?

Comment: How can i use this in apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys_refcursor` is the data type that you seemingly want to return.  That's a generic type for a weak ref cursor.  My guess is that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_03Recherche (
  p_titre_art VARCHAR2, 
  p_nom_aut VARCHAR2, 
  p_type_art VARCHAR2
)
  RETURN sys_refcursor;
IS
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc
   FOR select *
         from bi_articles art
              inner join BI_ArticlesAuteurs art_auth
                 on (art.isbn = art_auth.isbn)
              inner join BI_Auteurs auth
                 on (art_auth.auteurID = auth.auteurID)
        where titre LIKE p_titre_art
          and (nom LIKE p_nom_auth or
               prenum LIKE p_nom_auth)
          and typearticle LIKE type_art;

  RETURN l_rc;
END;
```

Now, a few suggestions

- Doing a `select *` is almost always a bad idea.  Particularly when you are joining multiple tables.  Do you really, really want the structure of the result set to change every time someone adds an additional column to any of three tables?  That seems unlikely.
- Use aliases everywhere.  Looking at the code, I have no idea what table `titre` comes from.  Or `nom` or `prenum` or `typearticle`.  Use aliases to identify which table a column comes from.  That makes your code clearer and makes it more robust when additional tables or columns are added in the future which may have the same column names (multiple entities might have a `nom` column for example).

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Actually, the select * and the missing table names are a result of my problems, so I've been testing a lot of stuff and I just happened to post the ugly version that was simplified as much as possible to try to find the bug. I'll test your idea right now

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error (ORA-24344: success with compilation error) with your code (did not change anything). Did it work in the "real" Oracle? I'm starting the suspect that the problem is because of Apex.

Comment: What does "show error" show?  Or query from `user_errors` or `all_errors`.  You haven't posted a reproducible test case so I can't test my answer.  I did notice a typo that I just fixed.  But there could be more that I'm not seeing.

Comment: query from all_errors gives me: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge